# DELETE RECORDS IN DATABASE USING VALUES IN COMBO BOX VB.NET PROGRAM

Tags: vb.net, combobox

```
Using con As New SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-ATS5HNK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=RESERVEDATA;Integrated Security=SSPI;"),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE [EMP] WHERE [SNO] = @SNO", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SNO", ComFilList.Items)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

VALUES IN ComFilList (COMBO BOX)
1
6
**EXISTING DATA**
SNO NAME    AMT
5   RAJ KUMAR   10500
1   KISHAN REDDY    12000
2   RAJIV SINGH 14000
4   KASHINATH   15000
3   MOHD YOUNUS 11500
6   JACKSON 16000
7   RAMA SHARMA 25000

Want to DELETE MULTIPLE "SNO" available in comfillist combo box. can anyone help me with this

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking how to delete multiple records or how to get multiple records from a list box? Combobox allows a single selection.

Assumptions:

1. we are using multiselect ListBox (not Combobox) to show a list of people
2. each item is an instance of object Person with id and name
3. we will create a comma separated list of selected people using id
4. add System.Linq to using statement

showing examples in c#, but concept is similar in VB.net

Person class

```
  public class Person {
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return $"{name} ({id})";
        }
    }
```

Fill list

```
    private void FillList() {
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Person { id = 1, name = "KUMAR" });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Person { id = 2, name = "KISHAN" });
    }
```

Make string of selected items

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var l = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<Person>().Select(p => p.id).ToArray();
        string selectedIds = string.Join(",", l);
    }
```

modify DELETE

```
DELETE [EMP] WHERE [SNO] IN(@SNOLIST)
```

use resulting selectedIds in your query

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SNO", selectedIds)
```

Make sure to check if anything is selected before running delete.

---

For names use the following:

build list of names (note that each gets wrapped into ', if value has ' it gets escaped as '', so for instance O'Connor becomes O''Connor

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var l = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<Person>().Select(p => ("'" + p.name?.Replace("'", "''") + "'")).ToArray();
        string selectedNames = string.Join(",", l);
}
```

modify DELETE

```
DELETE [EMP] WHERE [Name] IN (@selectedNames)
```

use selectedNames when adding parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SNO", selectedNames)
```

Comment: Yes i want to delete n number of records where SNO(column) values from combo box. For Ex: "DELETE [TABLENAME] WHERE [COLUMN NAME] IN ('VALUES')" This is working fine directly in daabase. I would like to apply same through vb.net code where column values to delete were in combo box.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for numeric parameters. Can u please suggest for ** string parameters** also

Comment: @RajeshSubramanya Posted solution that uses string parameters